# Js unable to prevent default action for cmd+w inside chromium(brave) browser

Tags: javascript, browser, hotkeys, preventdefault

Im using `react-hotkeys-hook` library to assign a shortcut to keyboard combinations.
cmd+r/cmd+t are being prevented from their default behavior but when it comes to cmd+w it doesnt.

here is the library in action

````
useHotkeys(('cmd+w' && 'ctrl+w'), (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e, '----event----');
    dispatch(sendGoogleReview(someVariable));
  });```

is this a browser restriction?

I tried other approaches aswell all yielding the same result
````

Comment: I think you are not implementing the parameters correctly. try using one key and see if it is working or not : `useHotkeys('cmd+w', e => { e.preventDefault() })`

Comment: They work i tried both ways